# Using Streamreader across formshow to use a streamreader across forms

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, streamwriter

Using VB.Net within VS2008.  My main form (frmMain) uses a streamwriter to create log that I write to for various events.  The log variable name is "LOG" so I do a Log.Writeline() to post to the log which works fine within the main form but if I load another form for options or maintenance functions I can't write to the log and if I use a new streamwriter it gives errors.

Thoughts on how I can use a streamwriter across forms?  I can access controls easily with . but it doesn't work with streamwriter.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you at least considered using the My.Application.Log object?  Made to do this.

Comment: No I hadn't thought of that. I'll take a look at that but I've also the got the class working too so i'm not sure what is more efficient or better..

Comment: That Log object works too and is code you don't have to maintain.  It is up to you of course.  The comment was meant to help other programmers that google your question some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to create a static class that holds an open StreamWriter and uses SyncLocks to ensure that only one thread at a time can use the open writer.

Here is a brief example:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading

Public Class ApplicationLog

    Private Shared m_LogWriter As StreamWriter

    Shared Sub New()
        Dim theType As Type
        Dim fClearSettings As Boolean = True

        ' Get the class object in order to take the initialization lock
        theType = GetType(ApplicationLog)

        ' Protect thread locks with Try/Catch to guarantee that we let go of the lock.
        Try
            ' See if anyone else is using the lock, grab it if they're not
            If Not Monitor.TryEnter(theType) Then

                ' Just wait until the other thread finishes processing, then leave if the lock was already in use.
                Monitor.Enter(theType)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Try
                ' Create a debug listener and add it as a debug listener
                m_LogWriter = New StreamWriter(New FileInfo("C:\mylog.txt").Open(FileMode.Append, IO.FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))

                fClearSettings = False
            Catch
                ' Ignore the error
            End Try

            ' Rest the var if something went wrong
            If fClearSettings Then
                m_LogWriter = Nothing
            End If
        Finally
            ' Remove the lock from the class object
            Monitor.Exit(theType)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub WriteToLog(ByVal sMessageText As String)
        Try
            ' Make sure a tracing file is specified.
            If m_LogWriter IsNot Nothing Then
                SyncLock m_LogWriter
                    m_LogWriter.WriteLine(sMessageText)
                    m_LogWriter.Flush()
                End SyncLock
            End If
        Catch
            ' Ignore any exceptions.
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I had read where I would have to do a Class but don't have much experience with writing classes.  What you've given is great except "Monitor" and FileInfo are throwing errors about not being defined.  Can you give a little context around that to help a newbie out?

Comment: Figured out system.threading had to be imported for monitoring.  working on fileinfo().

Comment: I've added the appropriate imports statements to the answer; FileInfo is in the System.IO namespace

Comment: Add system.io was not imported.  Now to try using it.

Comment: Okay, dumb question..  I've got the Class built and syntax errors cleaned up.  What do I use to write to the log?  I've tried m_LogWriter("MESSAGE") and WriteToLog("Message") and it comes up as an unrecognized command.  Do i have to do something special so the class is initialized and visible across each form?

Comment: RESOLVED.  ApplicationLog.WriteToLog("Message") works great.  I really appreciate the class help!!

Comment: Should I add a procedure to the class to close/dispose the log when closing the application?  I did that lastnight and all seems to work.

Comment: It won't hurt anything to add that, but when the app closes, it will tear down all of the objects, so it will be implicitly closed. We've been running similar code in production for 8+ years across all types of apps (win forms, IIS, services) and have never had an issue with not explicitly closing it.

Comment: Re Resolved: That is great news, glad I could help. Remember, if an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you click on the checkmark next to the answer and click the up arrow. This way future visitors to the question will know that this resolved your issue. Thanks!